# Package naming for different jars

Tags: java, jar, naming-conventions, package

Assume I have a project `A` in eclipse that produces `jar1`. And project `B` in eclipse that produces `jar2`.
Is it a bad idea for both project to use the same package naming?

Comment: Just consider what will happen if you need both in the Classpath. If that will work, then there should be no problem.

Comment: @ThorbjornRavnAndersen:But what does this depend on?If there no classes with same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are totally sure that these projects will be always used mutually exclusively then it's okay. If in future these two projects are referenced by third project then there will be a situation in which ambiguity may arise. Moreover if project A refer to project B or vice-versa then also ambiguous situation may arise. So it's really better to have different package naming while creating a project (to keep them unique)

Comment: Just to be clear.I am only refering about package names.Class names will be different

Comment: It will be difficult to say from which project and which jar this Class comes from, so i think it's quite bad idea to use same packages in different projects.